# set custom sum-by-color formula in vba

Tags: vba, excel, sum

```
Sub sumexeptblack()

    For Each cell In Range("4:4")
      If cell.Font.Color <> 0 Then
         Range("A3").Value = Range("A3").Value + cell.Value
      End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```

I write this code and it works, but when I just put it on another loop excel just calculating without any error or results. the second code is:

```
Sub sumallrowcolored()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim e As Integer
    e = 1

    For i = 2 To 168 Step 2
        e = i - e
        For Each cell In Range("i:i")
           If cell.Font.Color <> 0 Then
              Range("Ae").Value = Range("Ae").Value + cell.Value
           End If
        Next cell
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Where you've used `Range("i:i")` what would you like for this to be for each loop? Because `Range("2:2")` will error, as will any where no column letter is provided.

Comment: @Jordan - `Range("2:2")` is `A2:XFD2` or the entire second row. Proof in the Immediate window with `?Range("2:2").Address`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I understand your code correctly, you're trying to iterate through all cells of a row (in the first part the row is `4`, in the second part it is `i`). If this is the case you'll have to adjust your code like this:

```
Sub sumallrowcolored()
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim e As Integer
  e = 1
  For i = 2 To 168 Step 2
    e = i - e
    For Each cell In Range(i & ":" & i)
      If cell.Font.Color <> 0 Then
         Range("A" & e).Value = Range("A" & e).Value + cell.Value
      End If
    Next cell
  Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks alot ... it works

with a little change, ' e= i - e ' must be ' e = i - 1 '

Answer (score 1):

You need to examine when to use quotes and when not to use quotes when defining a [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx).

```
Dim cell as range
Dim i As Long, e As Long
e = 1
For i = 2 To 168 Step 2
    e = i - e
    'For Each cell In Rows(i)        'could also be Range(i & ":" & i)
    'better to cut it down to the .UsedRange
    For Each cell In Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Rows(i))
       If cell.Font.Color <> 0 Then
          'the following is a match operation; string concatenation should be a &, not a +
          Range("A" & e) = Range("A" & e).Value + cell.Value
       End If
    Next cell
Next i
```

The string concatenation operator is a **&** in VBA, not a **+**. The **+** is for mathematical addition. I'm not entirely sure which you actually want.

Answer (score 0):

For your second part of code you need to keep the `e` variable outside of the speech marks as it's only declared in VBA. Try:

```
Sub sumallrowcolored()

Dim i As Integer
Dim e As Integer
e = 1

For i = 2 To 168 Step 2
    e = i - e
    For Each cell In Range("i:i")
       If cell.Font.Color <> 0 Then
          Range("A" & e).Value = Range("A" & e).Value + cell.Value
       End If
    Next cell
Next i

End Sub
```